# How can i check double array for uniqueness?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

For example we have

`String [][] doubleArray = {{"a","1"},{"b","3"},{"a","1"},{"c","1"}};`.

How can i create a new array with only uniqueness subarrays :

`{{"a","1"},{"b","3"},{"c","1"}}`

What i tryed :

`Set <String []> uniq = new HashSet<String []>(Arrays.asList(doubleArray));`

But Java doesnt see the difference between `{"a","1"}` and `{"a","1"}` , so `uniq` returns me set of all subarrays of `doubleArray`, including clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map` like this:

```
String [][] doubleArray = {{"a","1"},{"b","3"},{"a","1"},{"c","1"}};
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String[] strings : doubleArray) {
    map.put(strings[0], strings[1]);
}
System.out.println("map = " + map);
```

The result:

```
map = {a=1, b=3, c=1}
```

Comment: This is wrong! If the original array contains `{a,1},{a,2}` what will be the result? We have the same kay - `a` with two different values, so the second will override the first.

Comment: @TDG I know, but in the question there is no something you mentioned. Thanks!